# TableView Crashes when i try to load data from a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I am trying to load the data from firebase database. I am able to retrieve the data using blocks and updating the values in an NSArray. I am able to print the data so i know the data is available. When i try to reload the table view the app crashes. any suggestions with the code ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"New Chat";

    FetchUsers *instance = [[FetchUsers alloc]init];

    [instance userInformationSucessBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          _nameOfUser = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
          _emailOfUser = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Email"];
          [self.tableView reloadData];
      });
}];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

      return self.nameOfUser.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ComposeCell"];
cell.textLabel.text =  self.nameOfUser[indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Crash Log

```
 2017-07-26 16:39:37.333 ChatApp[2870:141943] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000227b40
 2017-07-26 16:39:37.339 ChatApp[2870:141943] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000227b40'
 *** First throw call stack:
()
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095cbb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109030141 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010963b134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109552840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001095523b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   ChatApp                             0x000000010777ca54 -[ComposeViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 100
6   UIKit                               0x0000000109b64dbb -[UITableView _numberOfRowsInSection:] + 57
7   UIKit                               0x0000000109d9b176 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2344
8   UIKit                               0x0000000109d9f19f -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 95
9   UIKit                               0x0000000109b41eb8 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 121
10  UIKit                               0x0000000109b41508 -[UITableView reloadData] + 2013
11  ChatApp                             0x000000010777c8f1 __36-[ComposeViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_2 + 65
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b35e4a6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b38705c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b36840b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109590909 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109556ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2164
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109556016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010c498a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
19  UIKit                               0x00000001099ef134 UIApplicationMain + 159
20  ChatApp                             0x000000010777d0cf main + 111
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b3d365d start + 1
22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: invoking in `[self.tableView reloadData];` from `viewDidLoad` is pointless, even when you posted this on main dispatch queue. I would be surprised if exception is thrown that you are doing something on view which is not visible yet.

Comment: any suggestions how i can get this working ?

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Comment: -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800023a000
2017-07-26 16:16:06.312 ChatApp[2634:127808] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800023a000'

Comment: why the dispatch_async to the main queue in -viewDidLoad? You are already on the main queue at this point, using GCD here is not a good idea.

Comment: @pradeep You are trying to show a cell for every character in your  nameOfUser ?? why you need do that?

Comment: Go to "Breakpoint navigator", press `+` and select "Exception Beakpoint…" , rerun scenario and see where it happens (program will stop exacly at that place). Than copy paste call stack here.

Comment: the crash occur's in the numberOfRowsInSectionMethod. I have updated the crash log in main description.

Comment: @ReinierMelian i am trying to display all the name in the array on a tableView.

Comment: @MarekR  when i try with the exception breakpoint i get the following

-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000425500

Comment: @pradeep Can you post you dictionary response because i think you are not getting array in _nameOfUser

Comment: @pradeep With the exception breakpoint  program will stop exactly at place where exception accrues. 
When program stops inspect your call stack and variable values to catch actual error. Apparently problem is in code which we do not see. Your `self.nameOfUser` doesn't contain `NSArray` so problem is in initialization of this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] is not an array but a string. So when you assign _nameOfUser to it and reloadData, the tableView delegate tries to get count of a NSString and that is not available so it crash.
You need to properly extract your data.

Comment: this solution worked. i modified my code to store strings in an MutableArray and was able to print the data. Thank you !!